# How to debug code copied from FLASH to RAM in Atmel Studio?

Tags: debugging, gcc, arm, gdb

I have a custom boot loader program.  The loader must be able to program any part of the flash, including upgrading itself.  To accomplish this, the loader startup code copies the whole program from flash into RAM and then jumps to main().

The program works fine, but I can't get the debugger to set breakpoints.  The specific error message that I get is "Unable to set requested breakpoint on target".  Reading the state of variables and single stepping DOES seem to work.

**How can I get the debugger to work in this setup?**

Development Environment:  Atmel Studio 7
Processor:  ATSAME70 (This is an ARM Cortex M7)
Compiler:  GCC
Tool:  Atmel-ICE
Interface:  SWD (Serial Wire Debug)

The relevant portions of the linker script look like this...

```
/* Memory Spaces Definitions */
MEMORY
{
    rom (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x00400000, LENGTH = 0x00004000 /* rom, 2097152K */
    ram (rwx)   : ORIGIN = 0x20400000, LENGTH = 0x00060000 /* ram, 393216K */
}

SECTIONS
{
    .reset : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP("Device_Startup/startup.o"(.text))
        KEEP(*(.reset_code))
    } > rom
    PROVIDE(_exit = .);

    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _rom_to_ram_copy_vma_start = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
        *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
        ...
        ...
        _rom_to_ram_copy_vma_end = .;     
    } > ram AT > rom
    _rom_to_ram_copy_lma_start =  LOADADDR(.text);    
}
```

The program coplies everthing between _rom_to_ram_copy_vma_start  and _rom_to_ram_copy_vma_end into RAM and then jumps to main in RAM.

Given that I used "ram AT > rom" in the linker script one would think that the debugger should know that the code is in RAM and should have no problem setting the breakpoint there.

Comment: what happens when you build a test program for ram (not ram at rom), add some code to copy that and then use the debugger.  Did you confuse the debugger with this linker script?  does the specific hardware not support breakpoints in ram?

Comment: actually if you are using a debugger just write a few line of asm program that has a loop, and use the debugger to load and run that in ram, avoiding flash all together and see if it can generate a breakpoint  .thumb; .syntax unified; loop: adds r0,#1; adds r0,#1; b loop  arm-whatever-as so.s -o so.o arm-whatever-ld -Ttext=0x20000000 so.o -o so.elf

Comment: you can do this as two programs and avoid the this at that since it is designed as a complete copy and jump.  build for ram make that binary, create another copy and jump program and include the real binary as data and copy and jump.    both programs are simpler to link and build.

Comment: @old_timer Doing a pure RAM build works.  The debugger loads the code directly from my ELF file into RAM.  I can set breakpoints in the code running from RAM.  Still the mystery of why the original setup doesn't work remains.

Comment: The debugger clearly doesnt deal with the two address spaces, what do the symbols and memory regions look like in the elf file?  Or make your life easier in general and just avoid the ram at flash thing.  (or as in my case never use a debugger and be even happier)